# Typeahead select and change

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js

I'm not using Angular and I'm trying to figure how to make this:
http://plnkr.co/edit/pFsPx0lTM7OZVwF97m1l?p=preview
Well this but little bit more complicated.

Thing like in example above but not only show shortcut of the country when I type full contry name. Also whenever I type ANY letter it should display possiblities of shortcuts. Egzample.
I type: "Po..." should display shortcut for Poland (PL), and Portugal (PT), and limit It to show max 3.

```
var country = new Bloodhound({
datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,

remote: {
url: 'typeahead.php?query=%QUERY%',
wildcard: '%QUERY%',
cache: false
}
});

$('#country .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
display: 'country_name',
source: country,
} 
);
```

I think i should use SELECT and CHANGE but i don't know how.

**UPDATE**

This is code for SELECT.

```
jQuery('#country .typeahead').on('typeahead:select', function (e, datum) {
console.log(datum);
});
```

In firebug I see that its returing objects from my database, but now I need grab only one type of value and spit It out.

Answer (score 0):

For limit to show with min 3 letters: Add `minLength: 3`. With this parameter you need write min 3 letters for list appear.

```
$('#country .typeahead').typeahead({
        minLength: 3
    },
    {
        display: 'country_name',
        source: country,
});
```